# ZeroMQ Subscriber filtering on multipart messages

Tags: filtering, zeromq

With ZeroMQ `PUB/SUB` model, is it possible for a subscriber to filter based on contents of more than just the first frame?

For example, if we have a multi-frame message that contains three frames
**1)** data type,
**2)** instrument,
 and then **3)** the actual data,
is it possible to subscribe to a specific data type, instrument pair?

(All of the examples I've seen only shows filtering based off of the first message of a multipart message).

Answer (score 0):

### Different modes of ZeroMQ PUB/SUB filtering

Initial ZeroMQ model used a **sub**scriber-side subscription-based filtering.

That was easier for **pub**lisher, as it need not handle **sub**scriber-specific handling and simply fed all data to all `SUB`-s ( yes, at the cost of the vasted network traffic and causing **`SUB`**-side workload to process all incoming `BLOB`s, all the way up from the `PHY`-media, even if it did not **sub**scribe to the particular **`topic`**. Yes, pretty expensive in low-latency designs )

---

### **`PUB`**-side filtering was initially proposed for later implementation

still, this mode does not allow your idea to fly just on using the `PUB/SUB` **S**caleable **F**ormal **C**ommunication **P**attern.

ZeroMQ protocol design strives to inspire users, how to achieve just-enough designed distributed systems' behaviour.

As understood from your 1-2-3 intention, a custom logic shall be just enough to achieve the desired processing.

---

### So, how to approach the solution?

Do not hesitate to setup several messaging / control relays in parallel in your application domain-specific solution, it works much better for any tailor-made solutions and a way safer than to try to ***"bend"*** a library's primitive archetype ( in this case the trivial `PUB/SUB` **`topic`**-based filtering ) to make something a bit different, than for what an original use-case was designed.

The more true, if your domain-specific use is FOREX / Equity trading, where latency is your worst enemy, so a successful approach has to minimise stream-decoding and alternative branching as much as possible.

### nanoseconds do matter

If one reads into details about multiframe composition ( a sender-side `BLOB` assembly ), there is no latency-wise advantage, as the whole `BLOB` gets onto wire only after it has been completed - se there is no advantage for your `SUB`-side in case your idea was to handle initial frame content for signalling, as the whole `BLOB` arrives "together"